# Struggle with how to get something from my database with Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hi!

Sorry the title isn't that explicite, but I'm a beginner and I really don't have the vocabulary just yet

I've been struggling for hours with something, so before I trow my computer by the window, I came to ask for help :3

In my database I have a table with exhibitors and an other one with labels for those exhibitors. It's a many to many relationship and on my Controller I get the exhibitors with they labels that way :

```
        $exposants = Expo::where('this_year', 1)->with('labels')->get();
```

It's working great! But now I want more!

I need to get the Exhibitors with a specific label. Let's say I want the exhibitors who would come this year with they labels {that part I already have} but only those who have the column "name" on the "label" table  equal to "food". How do I do that ?

Please help my

Comment: Welcome to SO ... see if this helps you out https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Thank you! It's working with :

$exposants = Expo::whereHas('labels', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('name', 'food');
})->get();

But I can't use my "$request" in there (where the food word is supposed to come from xD) and laravel is not happy when I try to pass it to the function :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```php
$exposants = Expo::where('this_year', 1)
    ->whereHas('labels', fn($q) => $q->where('name', $request->input('labelName'))
    ->with('labels')
    ->get(); 


//OR using non-arrow closure for PHP 7.3 and lower

$exposants = Expo::where('this_year', 1)
    ->whereHas('labels', function($q) use($request){ 
        $q->where('name', $request->input('labelName'));
    })
    ->with('labels')
    ->get();

//replace labelName with whatever key you have on request
```

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: Thank you!! I've try something very similar, and it's working, but is it won't let me user the $request inside the function and I need the $request to get the "food" word. 

That's already a good beginning! Thank's a lot! :3

Comment: @EnidBonhamCarter Have updated the answer to get the label name from request  - pls check

Comment: Working perfectly!! You're my favorite person today, thanks a lot!! :3

Comment: @EnidBonhamCarter Side note: You should upgrade PHP version to 7.4 at the very least as 7.3 is now EOL - if you are still on 7.3. You may mark the answer as accepted/upvote for the benefit of subsequent visitors.